# Issue in metpy imports

Tags: import, package, metpy

I installed metpy with pip in order to plot a skewT diagram.
I have the following issue when I try to import metpy packages:

```
File "/home/straussc/Documents/stage2A/observations/programmes/trace_skewT.py", line 10, in <module>
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/metpy/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .units import (_mutate_arguments, DimensionalityError, is_quantity, UndefinedUnitError,

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/metpy/units.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pint

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pint/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .formatting import formatter, register_unit_format

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pint/formatting.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .babel_names import _babel_lengths, _babel_units

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pint/babel_names.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import HAS_BABEL

  File "/home/straussc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pint/compat.py", line 34, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Self  # noqa

ImportError: cannot import name 'Self' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

Does someone understand where it comes from?

Answer (score 1):

`typing_extensions` in your environment is outdated and in conflict with newer installs of `pint`, the units library MetPy relies on. Update the outdated package with

```bash
pip install --upgrade typing_extensions
```

and you should be good to go. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/1802) to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: It solved my issue. Thank you!